# Newton's method optimization for Deep Learning

Tags: machine-learning, optimization

I'm reading this paper "[Deep learning via Hessian-free optimization](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~jmartens/docs/Deep_HessianFree.pdf)" by J. Martens, I am having difficulty figure out the following statement:

> In the standard Newton's method, $q_{\theta}(p)$ is optimized by computing the $N\times N$ matrix $B$ and then solving the system $Bp = −\nabla f(\theta)$.

<sub>(section 3 of the paper)</sub>

Is there any theorem, or statement anywhere regarding why the above system needs to be solved to optimize the local approximation? I came across another paper that has a reference to J. Martens and has used the same statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at section 2, it says

> The central idea motivating Newton’s method is that $f$ can be locally
>   approximated around each $\theta$, up to 2nd-order, by the quadratic: $$ f(\theta + p) \approx q_\theta(p) \equiv f(\theta) + \nabla f(\theta)^Tp + \frac{1}{2} p^TBp \, \, (1) $$  where $B = H(\theta)$ is the
>   Hessian matrix of $f$ at $\theta$. Finding a good search direction then reduces
>   to minimizing this quadratic with respect to $p$.

To minimize, you need to take the derivative of (1) with respect to $p$ and set it to zero:

$$\Rightarrow \nabla f(\theta) + Bp = 0$$

which is equivalent to $Bp = -\nabla f(\theta)$.